# Submit multiple forms from one page on same table

Tags: php, mysqli

Currently I'm developing a logistic website and the idea is the following:

We have a pickup address and we can have multiple delivery addresses.

This is the table we use:

```
id     | order_id     | user_id     | company      | address     | postal     | city     | order_number | license_plate | qty | unit | instructions | type | status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0      | 10000        | 1           | Company A    | Street 1    | 00000      | City A   | 123123123    | xx-xxx-x      | 1   | M3   | blabla       | P    | 0
1      | 10000        | 1           | Company A    | Street 1    | 00000      | City B   | 123123123    | xx-xxx-x      | 1   | M3   | blabla       | D    | 0
2      | 10000        | 1           | Company A    | Street 1    | 00000      | City B   | 123123123    | xx-xxx-x      | 1   | M3   | blabla       | D    | 0
```

One pickup address ( type = P ) can have multiple delivery addresses.

Based on the order_id all addresses are shown. The transporter needs to fill in the order_number, qty and unit field per address.

We use the following php file to execute the form. But when I fill in the fields on the first form and click on save the order_number, qty and unit is filled in on all 3 table rows.

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';

/* code for update orders */
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
    $SQL = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id=".$_GET['edit']);
    $getROW = $SQL->fetch_array();
}

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $SQL = $MySQLiconn->query("UPDATE orders SET order_number='".$_POST['order_number']."', 
            qty='".$_POST['qty']."',
            unit='".$_POST['unit']."',
            status='".$_POST['status']."'
            WHERE order_id=".$_GET['edit']);
}
/* code for data update */

?>

<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="container">
    <div id="pickupform">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                $res = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE type='P' AND order_id=".$_GET['edit']);
                while($row=$res->fetch_array())
                {
                    ?>
                    <!-- Delivery Address-->
                    <div class="formcontainer col-push-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Afleveradres</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p><?php echo $row['company']; ?><br/>
                        <?php echo $row['address']; ?><br/>
                        <?php echo $row['postal']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['city']; ?></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Ordernumber -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ordernummer / Lieferschein</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                      <input id="order_number" name="order_number" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $row['order_number']; ?>" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['order_number'];  ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Quantity / Unit -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Hoeveelheid / Quantity</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" placeholder="Bijv. 100" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['qty'];  ?>" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <input id="unit" name="unit" type="text" placeholder="Bijv. M3" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['unit'];  ?>"value="test2" style="margin-left:-1px" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Send Consignment -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit']))?>1"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="update"></label>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) { ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Opslaan</button>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div id="deliveryform">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <?php
                $res = $MySQLiconn->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE type='D' AND order_id=".$_GET['edit']);
                while($row=$res->fetch_array())
                {
                    ?>

                    <div class="formcontainer col-push-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Afleveradres</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <p><?php echo $row['company']; ?><br/>
                        <?php echo $row['address']; ?><br/>
                        <?php echo $row['postal']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['city']; ?></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Ordernummer / Lieferschein</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                      <input id="order_number" name="order_number" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $row['order_number']; ?>" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['order_number'];  ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Hoeveelheid / Quantity</label>  
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="qty" name="qty" type="text" placeholder="Bijv. 100" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['qty'];  ?>" />
                            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:0px;"></span>
                            <input id="unit" name="unit" type="text" placeholder="Bijv. M3" class="form-control input-md" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) echo $getROW['unit'];  ?>"value="test2" style="margin-left:-1px" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="1"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="update"></label>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <?php if(isset($_GET['edit'])) { ?>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Opslaan</button>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I'm not that familiair with PHP, could you guys help me out on this one? So per address I need to submit the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your first form, add a hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' name='type' value='P' />
```

This will submit the value 'P' into $_POST['type'].

Then modify your update query to use this value in the WHERE clause:

```
....WHERE order_id=".$_GET['edit'])." AND type='".$_POST['type']."';
```

(Don't forget the single quotes - 'P' is a string.)
This should then only update the matching rows.

Then, do the same for the second form, using the value 'D'.

Comment: Thanks, but the second form can also have multiple addresses, and the transporters needs to fill the values in when he arrives at delivery address a and when he arrives at delivery address 2. etc etc. Sometimes one pickup can have 5 different delivery addresses.

Comment: The solution above would update every row that matches the order_id and either 'P' or 'D' depending on the form submitted.

Comment: Yes, i understand. But wat if I have the following situation: 1 pick-up form and 3 delivery forms on one page

Comment: There are only 2 different forms in your example.  Add the hidden field once in each form, outside the loop.

Comment: The while statement generates multiple forms, i see i have to move the form tag within the while query. Do i need to add a unique nr to the delivery type? If i want to have more than 2 forms?